# iOS app getting data from server

Tags: php, ios, firebird

I will be writing an IOS app that will query data from a server.  What is the proper method to request and retrieve data in that manner.  None of the books I'm reading seem to be covering it.  I imagine the server would be using something  like PHP and it would have access to the database.  Would the iOS app do something like XML-RPC and i write php functions to listen, retrieve, and respond? Is XML-RPC even still the hip solution or is there something more modern I've not used yet?

The iOS app will be ultimately trying to get information from a Firebird database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're creating an iOS 5 app, then you're on luck, you can use restful webservices very easily:

```
NSString* response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:<url pointing to your server> error:&error];
```

Then you can use `NSJsonSerialization` to convert the response into a property list. Also there are convenience methods for parsing XML files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various methods like this:

1. Simple Get or Post Request.
2. XML SOAP Services.
3. REST JSON Services.

This depends the data you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest looking into [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

It is amazingly documented, Extremely powerful and easy to pick up.

Download the files drag and drop them into your project. Import ASIHTTPRequest.h.
Then you can do all of this 
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

I figure I should put the disclaimer that the developer no longer supports the project, However, it works amazing and since it is so widely used i'm sure if there is ever a major issue with it in the future someone will take the liberty of fixing it and putting it up on github for all.